# How to get the id of display image in flipper?

Tags: android

BELOW IS MY CODE. This code is working, but I want to get the value of the display image in array to test, if the display country is correct. Please help me . I'm stuck in this activity. Thanks for all help .

```
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        private boolean blocked = false;
        private Handler handler = new Handler();
            ViewFlipper flippy;
        Button show;
        TextView view;
        int flags[] = { R.drawable.afghan, R.drawable.albania, R.drawable.algeria };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.flipper);
        flippy = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
        show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            for (int i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
            setflipperimage(flags[i]);

            }
        }

        private void setflipperimage(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Set Filpper Called", i + "");
        ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        image.setBackgroundResource(i);
        flippy.addView(image);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do not call this in loop,use this on click or on touch:

```
i+=1;
flippy.setDisplayedChild(flags[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get used to get the current child id

```
   viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();
```